# Qt 4 svg plugin vs the svg renderer

Tags: qt4

I am confused as to why there is an svg plugin (plugin/imageformats/qsvg4.dll) packaged together with qt when there exists a standalone svg renderer (Qtsvg4.dll).  Just what does the svg imageformats plugin do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin allows you to load svg images to e.g. QImage or QPixmap without further ado.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, from what I could tell it just uses an Qsvgrenderer under the covers